# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while setting up django-filer

Tags: python, django, apache, file-permissions, django-filer

I installed django-filer and am now testing out the upload function, but when I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /admin/filer/clipboard/operations/upload/
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/filer/admin/clipboardadmin.py", line 81, in ajax_upload
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     file_obj.save()
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/filer/models/imagemodels.py", line 56, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/filer/models/abstract.py", line 65, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     super(BaseImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/filer/models/filemodels.py", line 165, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/polymorphic/polymorphic_model.py", line 89, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     return super(PolymorphicModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 572, in save_base
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 597, in _save_parents
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     self._save_table(cls=parent, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     using=using, raw=raw)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 902, in execute_sql
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     for sql, params in self.as_sql():
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 860, in as_sql
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     for obj in self.query.objs
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 252, in pre_save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/filer/fields/multistorage_file.py", line 95, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     super(MultiStorageFieldFile, self).save(name, content, save)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/files.py", line 667, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     super(ThumbnailerFieldFile, self).save(name, content, *args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 86, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 49, in save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     name = self._save(name, content)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 172, in _save
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     os.makedirs(directory)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     makedirs(head, mode)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     makedirs(head, mode)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error]     mkdir(name, mode)
[Fri Jul 10 11:32:20 2015] [error] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/uronline/media/filer_public/3b'
```

I have have looked at quite a few other questions that mention this problem and here is what I have checked:

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Alias /media/ /home/uronline/media/

    <Directory /home/uronline/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I am using Apache, and the user is apache

All the folders in the path to the 'media' folder are set to 755 with user: apache, group: www

Just out of curiosity, I momentarily changed the folder permissions to 777 and still got the error.

I am using the default settings for django-filer and I am now wondering if this permissions error is caused by this?

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! As always, my problem was with SELinux

Turns out selinux has a boolean that "Allows httpd daemon to write files in directories labeled public_content_rw_t" - from http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

So this worked:

```
setsebool -P allow_httpd_anon_write on
```

Hope this helps someone!